# run-time error 287 - Outlook when set inspector.wordeditor

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set oMailItem = oApp.CreateItem(0)

oMailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText

Set oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector

oInspector.Display


MsgBox "IsWordMail = " & oInspector.IsWordMail & vbLf & "EditorType = " & (oInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord) ' Both are true.
```

Set wdDoc = oInspector.WordEditor '**<--Run-time error '287' Appication-Defined or Object-Defined Error**

option-mail- composer message in this format is "HTML"
outlook reference 16.0 is set up

Comment: Is Microsoft Word the default email editor? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376689/1467082

Answer (score 0):

If the code suddenly stopped working after migrating to Office 365 or for any other reasons, please refer to the code below. Comments have been added for easy understanding and implementation.

If you have administrative rights then you can also try the registry changes given at below link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/926512/information-for-administrators-about-e-mail-security-settings-in-outlo

However, I recommend a code that's Excel version independent of making system changes because system changes will be required on each end user's machine as well.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Email(ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strSubject As String)


    Dim rngToPicture As Range
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim Outmail As Object
    Dim strTempFilePath As String
    Dim strTempFileName As String

    'Name it anything, doesn't matter
    strTempFileName = "RangeAsPNG"

    'rngToPicture is defined as NAMED RANGE in the workbook, do modify this name before use
    Set rngToPicture = Range("rngToPicture")
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Outmail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Create an email
    With Outmail
        .To = strTo
        .Subject = strSubject

        'Create the range as a PNG file and store it in temp folder
        Call createPNG(rngToPicture, strTempFileName)

        'Embed the image in Outlook
        strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
        .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0

        'Change the HTML below to add Header (Dear John) or signature (Kind Regards) using newline tag (<br />)
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.png' style='border:0'>"


        .Display

    End With

    Set Outmail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set rngToPicture = Nothing

End Sub

Sub createPNG(ByRef rngToPicture As Range, nameFile As String)

    Dim wksName As String

    wksName = rngToPicture.Parent.Name

    'Delete the existing PNG file of same name, if exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png"
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy the range as picture
    rngToPicture.CopyPicture

    'Paste the picture in Chart area of same dimensions
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Add(rngToPicture.Left, rngToPicture.Top, rngToPicture.Width, rngToPicture.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        'Export the chart as PNG File to Temp folder
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "PNG"
    End With
    Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

End Sub
```