# MailItem Inspector.WordEditor generates Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, automation, outlook

I created a function that replaces a placeholder in MailItem body (oft). It is working in my machine but not the my client machine. Where both using MS Office 365.
Anyone resolved this issue?

```
Sub ReplaceInEmailBody(MyItem As Object, stringToReplace As String, str As String)
 Dim oDoc As Word.Document
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
 Set myInspector = MyItem.GetInspector
 
 Set oDoc = myInspector.WordEditor ----> generates Application-defined or object defined error

    With oDoc.Content.Find
        With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        .Execute FindText:=stringToReplace, ReplaceWith:=str, Format:=True, _
        Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor in Office 2016 generates Application-defined or object defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376329/mailitem-getinspector-wordeditor-in-office-2016-generates-application-defined-or)

Answer (score 0):

If the message is not currently being displayed, you can run into troubles with  the Word editor, especially if you are processing a large number of messages.

Try to replace text in the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property instead:

```
MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, stringToReplace, str)
```

Comment: The message is displayed before call that function. I use MailItem.Display.
MailItem.HTMLBody is not applicable in my use case because I'm modifying rich text type of email.