# Vba vba runtime error -1802485755(94904005)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, runtime-error

i have a strange problem, vba return me the error vba runtime error -1802485755(94904005) and i searched on internet and i found nothing, so i am tring to ask here if someone can help me

here is the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim str As New Classe1
    Dim ricerca As String
    Dim dmi As outlook.MailItem
    Dim UTCdate As Date, UTCdate2 As Date
    Dim out As outlook.Application
    Dim DATA1 As Date
    Dim DATA2 As Date
    Dim errorN As Long
    
    On Error GoTo FormatoErrato:
    DATA1 = DateAdd("h", 1, Res.DataStart.Value)
    DATA2 = DateAdd("h", 23, Res.DataEnd.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set out = New outlook.Application
    Set dmi = out.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    UTCdate = dmi.PropertyAccessor.LocalTimeToUTC(DATA1)
    UTCdate2 = dmi.PropertyAccessor.LocalTimeToUTC(DATA2)
    
    ricerca = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%sometext%'" & _
    " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <= '" & UTCdate2 & "'" & _
    " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" & UTCdate & "'"
    
    str.prova (ricerca)

FormatoErrato:
    errorN = Err.Number
    If errorN = 13 Then
        MsgBox "invalid format", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

this code (in a class module) is on a userform button where you set two dates and then the following code search the emails that strike the requirments

```
Sub prova(val As String)
    Res.Mezzi.Clear
    
    Dim fol As outlook.Folder
    Dim arr, arr2
    Dim ricerca As String, txt As String
    Dim n As Long, s As Long, tot As Long, l As Long
    Dim mi As outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Object
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    
    Set fol = 'outlook folder path'
    s = 0
    n = 1
    
    ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To s)
    
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(val)
        If i.Class = olMail Then
        Set mi = i
    
        Set doc = mi.GetInspector.WordEditor
            If doc.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                For tot = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
                    arr2(s) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(doc.Tables(tot).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text)
                    s = s + 1
                    ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To s)
                Next tot
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    For s = 0 To UBound(arr2)
        If IsEmpty(arr2(s)) = False And arr2(s) <> "" Then
            Res.Mezzi.AddItem arr2(s)
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

the email that i'm looking for has a table, one or more in it so i used getinspector.wordeditor to check if the table exist and then take the data that i need from it.

the sub works fine if the difference between the dates is just few days if i put a week give that error

coudl you help me to solve the problem or work around it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Where specifically is the error?  Note you should add `Exit Sub` after `str.prova  ricerca` (note no parentheses needed there) so your code doesn't run into the error handler.

Comment: @TimWilliams when occur is on the getinspector.wordeditor part

Comment: Is it failing on one specific mail?

Comment: @TimWilliams no i tried different data range,  the error occor when the range is over some days and probably over a numer of emails

Comment: What "this code (in a class module) is on a userform button" should mean? What `res` is, where was it declared and defined? Doesn't the mentioned error have a description?

Comment: @FaneDuru  this Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() is a button in a userform, 
Res is the userform name (sorry i did not say that)   
Mezzi is a listbox name.  
yes the description is  operation failed
just now i noted  that the nuber of the error change is not the same while the description is the same

Comment: Do you get the same problem when dealing with the `HTMLBody` property?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev i don't know  i have never used html body property, can  i do the same thing with those properties?

Comment: Does it generate the error like WordEditor?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any information which Office version is installed on the system. So, if you have a pretty old version of MS Office installed the following case makes sense - the `WordEditor` property is only valid if the `IsWordMail` method returns `True` and the `EditorType` property is `olEditorWord`.

The most-likely possible reason for such errors at runtime is security settings when dealing with the Outlook object model. The message body is a protected property in the Outlook object model which can generate errors when Outlook is automated from an external application. You can find the list of protected properties described on the [Protected Properties and Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/protected-properties-and-methods) page.

So, the Object Model Guard warns users and prompts users for confirmation when untrusted applications attempt to use the object model to obtain email address information, store data outside of Outlook, execute certain actions, and send email messages. If, for any reason, the warning is not appropriate or can't be displayed, the Outlook object model may generate errors when accessing protected properties.

In your scenario you can:

1. Use a low-level API which doesn't trigger security issues in the Outlook object model - Extended MAPI or any other third-party wrapper around that API.
2. Create a COM add-in which has access to the trusted Application object and which doesn't trigger security issues.
3. Install any AV with the latest updates.
4. Use group policy settings to setup security settings to not trigger security issues.

Comment: i have office 2016 installed, i can't understand why the error rise just if i am doing a research between 5 -6 days or more while if i do shorter research like one day or two i have no problem.

Comment: Are the older items cached in the Outlook store?

Comment: yes, the email that i am looking are all in the inbox folder

Comment: Do you get the same results with HTMLBody for these items?

Comment: i have never used htmlbody property, can i do the same thing like using wordeditor? where can i get some information about how to use htmlbody property?

Comment: HTMLBody is just a string (HTML) which represents the message body.

Comment: i tried with mail.body and in that way the macro don't fail but is difficult to get data in that way, because if on that email there is  text beside the table the  result  is ruined, instead if i look only in the table the result is always right

Comment: See [MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor in Office 2016 generates Application-defined or object defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376329/mailitem-getinspector-wordeditor-in-office-2016-generates-application-defined-or)

Answer (score 0):

after many trials i think i solved

to avoid to raise the error i should close the inspector.

in this way:

```
If i.Class = olMail Then
    Set mi = i
    Set insp = mi.GetInspector
    Set doc = insp.WordEditor
        If doc.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            For tot = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
                arr2(s) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(doc.Tables(tot).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text)
                s = s + 1
                ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To s)
            Next tot
        End If
    End If
     insp.Close olSave
```

now all seems to work fine even with range of 10 days of emails