# Copy Table from Excel and Paste as Image in Email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to copy a table range from a sheet in Excel and paste it into the body of an email in Outlook.

The script below opens the email and populates the "to:" and "Subject" lines, but the body of the email is blank.
The script is copying the image, because I can right click into the body of the email and paste the image. It's not pasting through the script.

```vb
Sub send_email_with_table_as_pic()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim table As Range
Dim pic As Picture
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim wordDoc

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'grab table, convert to image, and cut
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set table = ws.Range("E26:H38")

ws.Activate
table.Copy
Set pic = ws.Pictures.Paste
pic.Select
With Selection
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .ShapeRange.Height = 100
End With
pic.Cut

'create email message
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "team@abc.com"
    .cc = ""
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = "table data"
    .display
    
    Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    With wordDoc.Range
        .pasteandformat wdChartPicture
        .insertParagraphAfter
        .InsertAfter "Thank you,"
        .insertParagraphAfter
        .InsertAfter "Greg"
    End With
    
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style = font-size:11pt; font-family:Arial>" & _
    "Hi team, <p> Please see table below: <p>" & .HTMLBody
End With
On Error GoTo 0
    
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm wondering if I have improper settings in Outlook or Excel.
I copied most of this code from a tutorial that seemed to work for others.

Comment: `wdChartPicture` is a Word VBA constant and your Excel code won't know its value unless you've added a reference in your VBA project to the Word object library.  If you use `Option Explicit` it will warn you about thing like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little simpler and works for me:

```vb
Sub send_email_with_table_as_pic()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E26:H38").CopyPicture
    
    With OutMail
        .to = "team@abc.com"
        .cc = ""
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = "table data"
        .display
        
        Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        With wordDoc.Range
            .Paste
            wordDoc.InlineShapes(1).Height = 100
            .InsertParagraphAfter
            .InsertAfter "Thank you,"
            .InsertParagraphAfter
            .InsertAfter "Greg"
        End With
        
        .HTMLBody = "<BODY style = font-size:11pt; font-family:Arial>" & _
            "Hi team, <p> Please see table below: <p>" & .HTMLBody
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think I have a Group Policy setting on my work computer that is restricting the .GetInspector line. I ran the code you provided on my personal laptop and it worked the first time. Still not working on my work laptop.

Comment: Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376329/mailitem-getinspector-wordeditor-in-office-2016-generates-application-defined-or

Answer (score 0):

To make this code work, there are two possible solutions:

1. Replace the constant `wdChartPicture` with its value - **13**.

[image: constants value]

```vb
With wordDoc.Range
            .pasteandformat 13 ' <~ Replace the constant to value
            .insertParagraphAfter
            .InsertAfter "Thank you,"
            .insertParagraphAfter
            .InsertAfter "Greg"
        End With
```

#### OR

2. Add Tools -> References... -> Microsoft Word Object Library.

[image: references]

It works for me:

[image: result]